# With redux, why is mapStateToProps() not showing state in props when state is effectively changed in state tree?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to pass the state to as props through mapStateToProps(), and even though the state change is being reflected in the state tree (redux tool inspector) and the 'data' being passed down as the action payload is successfully logging in the reducer.js, the state is not being passed down as props in my container.

my reducer.js:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import { GOT_INDUSTRY_DATA } from './constants.js';

const initialState = fromJS({
    data: []
})

function industryDataReducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case GOT_INDUSTRY_DATA: {
            const { data } = action
            console.log('reducer data',data)
            return state.set('data', fromJS(data))
        }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default industryDataReducer
```

in my container:

```
    export class IndustryPage extends React.PureComponent { 

     render(){
      const { data } = this.props
      console.log(data)
      return{
        ...
      }
     }
    }

    function mapStateToProps({data}) {
     return {
      data
     }
    }

    const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
    const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'industry', saga })
    const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'industry', reducer })

    export default compose (
     withStyles(styles),
     withSaga,
     withReducer,
     withConnect
    )(IndustryPage);
```

[image: screenshot of data in state tree]

Comment: Is your component re-rendering on a prop change / after the redux state has updated? If not try using React's Component instead of PureComponent and see if that helps.

Comment: @RoyScheffers Thanks for the attempt Roy, unfortunately I am running into the same issue

Comment: Can you try using connect from redux only instead of the composed function chain? Be selective of what the app uses and try to narrow down on functionality. At some point, it will start working.  When did the problem start? What did you introduce? Also, would it be possible to have a repo online to experiment with?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing IndustryPage as a default import? If you have `import { IndustryPage } from '...'` (as opposed to `import IndustryPage from '...'`) where you're using the component, it would explain the weird behaviour.